# How to load an extension in Edge using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension, selenium-edgedriver

I want to load an extension in Edge while using Selenium in C#.
I have figured I have to use `EdgeOptions.AddExtensionPath()` but when passing the path no extensions are loaded.

The extension was extracted from `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Here is the part of the code used to initialize the EdgeDriver:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

public void InitializeNewDriver() {
    string microsoftWebDriverPath = @"some\path";

    EdgeDriverService service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(microsoftWebDriverPath);

    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.AddExtensionPath(@"path\to\extension\folder");

    Driver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);
}
```

Edit: I'm using Selenium.Webdriver v4.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to test the issue and found that if you pass the location of the extension to the `options.AddExtensionPath()` then the extension is not getting a load.

I suggest trying to use the `options.AddExtensions()` method and pass the `.CRX` file of the extension as a parameter.

It can help you to load the extension successfully.

**C# code example:**

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.UseChromium = true;
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
options.AddExtensions(@"Path_of_the_extension_here\extension.crx");
var driver = new Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools.EdgeDriver(@"Web_driver_path_here......", options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://Your_URL_will_be_here...");
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code sample as per your own requirements.

Comment: Thank you it's working now!

Also props to you for mentionning ``options.UseChromium = true;``, I didn't know it was necessary for extensions to be loaded and line switches to be taken into account.